# Joi nested when validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

I am trying to validate a nested object conditionally based upon a value in the parent.

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.string(),
    b: Joi.object({
        c: Joi.when(Joi.ref('..a'), { is: 'foo', then: Joi.number().valid(1), otherwise: Joi.number().valid(2) }),
    }),
});

const obj = {
    a: 'foo',
    b: {
        c: 2,
    },
};
```

In this example, I want to get an error that c must be 1, but the validation passes. I've tried with and without references, but I clearly must be misunderstanding something fundamental about how Joi works. Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need one more `.` in your `Joi.ref()` call. `..` will go up to the parent tree, then another dot to signify the property. So for your case it would go to the parent `..` then get the a property `parent.a`

Using the [Joi playground](https://joi.dev/tester/) this worked for me:

```js
Joi.object({
    a: Joi.string(),
    b: Joi.object({
        c: Joi.when(Joi.ref('...a'), {
            is: 'foo',
            then: Joi.number().valid(1),
            otherwise: Joi.number().valid(2)
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! And thanks also for the heads up about Joi playground.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need `Joi.ref`, this would still work with `...` referencing the parent's sibling, like [about14sheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9583747/about14sheep) pointed out in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71167417/10314151). I ended up doing something like this:

```
Joi.object({
    a: Joi.string(),
    b: Joi.object({
        c: Joi.when('...a', {
            is: 'foo',
            then: Joi.number().valid(1),
            otherwise: Joi.number().valid(2),
        }),
    }),
});
```